# Windows service suddenly not hit the break points in VS2010

Tags: windows-services, breakpoints

I have created a Windows service.  After a successful build, I installed the service and added that process with my main application debug.  Until last week, the Windows service was able to hit the break point.  Now I can't hit the break point.  Can anyone suggest a solution?

Comment: Are you compiling in debug or release mode?

Comment: debug mode..After i delete the temporary files.it can be hit the break point.